# Error while importing posts in wordpress from one host to another

Tags: php, wordpress, server, importerror, posts

I am importing a wordpress posts from one host to another.. while doing it,(i done it few times already in different projects) i have this error (image_attached) and 260 of 900 posts only imported.
[image: error in wordpress]

while i am giving ok in assign author it stated that this one,
[image]

While i am contacting the admin of the host, he states that it is wordpress error, not the host error, anyone knows how to solve this error. Any relevant ideas are welcome?

Comment: What is your wordpress version? 4.0?

Comment: and do you using latest version of import plugin?

Comment: yes.. Version 0.6.1 of wordpress importer..

Comment: Please refer : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24373